# Using a property as an attribute argument

Tags: c#, attributes, data-annotations

I have written a custom credit card validation attribute that checks CardNumber property is valid for a particular card type (another property in the same class)

```
[CardValidationBinCheck(this.CardType, 
                        ErrorMessage = "CreditCardNumberDoesNotMatchCardType")]
public string CardNumber
{
 ...
}
```

This won't compile as studio complains that attribute arguments must be constant, a typeof expression or an array creation expression of an attribute parameter type (?).

Is there anyway I can pass cirvumvent this and pass my `this.CardType` to the attribute?

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: You would have to convolute AOP to do it, but why are you doing this? One you can determine the CardType from the Credit Card number. Two, why not just have a method and place it into the set of your property to check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately not. Even if IL allows an attribute value to be a member reference token (e.g. a `PropertyInfo` effectively) there's no C# operator to get one for you<sup>1</sup>. You could pass it in as a string literal and then use reflection to get the `PropertyInfo` though. Ugly and fragile, but probably the closest you'll get.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is a well-known feature request, possibly called the "infoof" operator. There's no sign of it being implemented though.